# pkg-config is looking into /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig even with PKG_CONFIG_PATH set to another location

Tags: cross-compiling, pkg-config

I'm using pkg-config to cross compile a project to MIPS platform.
As usual, I'm setting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH var to the target's platform suitable directory (in this case something like /usr/local/mips_sdk/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig, but it doesn't matter).

Strange is that pkg-config is using .pc files from /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig when they are not found in the path pointed by PKG_CONFIG_PATH var.
It is like /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is hardcoded in the search path of pkg-config.

It feels a little strange because it will try to link system libraries (x86) to my mips compiled stuff.

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would approach debugging this problem: Run

```
strace -o makelog -f -ff -v -s 9000 make
```

This will create `makelog.<pid>` files for all processes run during compilation. With the options given they will contain a complete list of environment variables, so you should first of all be able to follow `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and see if/where it changes. You can also find things like if `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` is read from some configuration file or not for instance.

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry for taking this long to answer. I found the solution some time ago and forgot to get back here.

Comment: @Marcus A long shot, but do you remember what the solution was?

Comment: @Marcus yea please do post the solution. I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: Apologies. I really don't remember the solution. It's been 10 years. Please post here when you find the solution for it.